# Seeing changes on Google Directions Response overview_polyline.points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I am having some weird trouble with Directions Response. After a Directions Request I need to save the polyline, so till the point I have been getting the polyline with:

directions_result.routes[0].overview_polyline.points;

Which was working perfectly fine. According to the Google Directions API, the JSON response has the following format:

(see the whole JSON output here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)

{
  "status": "OK",
  "routes": [ {
    (lots of stuff),
    "overview_polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOnzh@vlbBtc~@tsE`vnApw{A`dw@~w\|tNtqf@l{Yd_Fblh@rxo@b}@xxSfytAblk@xxaBeJxlcBb~t@zbh@jc|Bx}C`rv@rw|@rlhA~dVzeo@vrSnc}Axf]fjz@xfFbw~@dz{A~d{A|zOxbrBbdUvpo@`cFp~xBc`Hk@nurDznmFfwMbwz@bbl@lq~@loPpxq@bw_@v|{CbtY~jGqeMb{iF|n\\~mbDzeVh_Wr|Efc\\x`Ij{kE}mAb~uF{cNd}xBjp]fulBiwJpgg@|kHntyArpb@bijCk_Kv~eGyqTj_|@`uV`k|DcsNdwxAott@r}q@*gc@nu`CnvHx`k@dse@j|p@zpiAp|gEicy@`omFvaErfo@igQxnlApqGze~AsyRzrjAb__@ftyB}pIlo_BflmA~yQftNboWzoAlzp@mz`@|}*@fda@jakEitAn{fB_a]lexClshBtmqAdmY_hLxiZd~XtaBndgC"
    },
    (and lot more stuff)

However, for the last couple of days, my code stopped working, so while debugging I found out that the call:

directions_result.routes[0].overview_polyline.points;

Was returning UNDEFINED, while simply

directions_result.routes[0].overview_polyline;

Is now returning me the wanted polyline.

I have consequently changed my code, as it seems to be working perfectly when removing the element points, but I have been desperately searching for more info on this change, any documentation in Google Maps API, any change notice, and I have found nothing.

Does someone have any idea of why is this happening?

I would appreciate some light thrown into this issue.

Thanks a Lot!!
Geno.

Comment: Did you specify a version in your API call? Not specifying a version will get you v3.exp as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning). *Changes made to the experimental version are not guaranteed to be feature stable.*

Comment: You are right, I did not specify it. Good to know, thanks for the clarification!!